# How can I put register key for advanced screen recorder that I made?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I made a screen recorder for PC.

I want to make the free version show the background name of the program.

After the registration is activated, I want to disable the name of program.

Comment: I assume that English is not your first language but that means that you need to make more of an effort to explain clearly, not less. What you have posted makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: i change this is ok or not please help me if you can

Comment: I don't know what "background name of program" means or "disable the name of the program". To be honest, even if you make those things clear, your question is still almost certainly to broad for this site. This site is for specific problems but if you haven't done anything then you haven't encountered a problem yet.

Comment: i mean logo or word show for free version and after registration not show logo or word

Comment: @NopSh Do you mean that you want to add a watermark to the output file?

Comment: yes andrew morton teach me please

Comment: @NopSh Perhaps [Can i add watermark on a series of pictures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041096/can-i-add-watermark-on-a-series-of-pictures) will help you; although it is in C# it shows all the methods to use in .NET.

Comment: vb.net not c# please

Comment: same copde vb.net and c# if yes thanks andrew

Comment: this where i added to key button or where